# Serialize / Deserialize QVariantMap with QDataStream between PyQt >> Qt-C++

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdatastream

I can Successfully Serialize / Deserialize QVariantMap through  QDataStream in the PyQt5

Python :

```
    data = {'mq_username': ('123'),  'np_database': ('png') ,  'category': ('png') ,  'enroll_name': ('png') ,  'notes': ('png') ,   'file': ('png') ,
            'np_database': ('png') , 'PNG-image': (png) }
    v = QVariant(data)
block = QByteArray()
    xout = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    xout.setVersion(qt.QDataStream.Qt_5_10)
    xout << v
    xox = (b'')
    xox = block.data()
```

This is perfectly fine to deserialize:

```
out = qt.QDataStream(block, qt.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        out.setVersion(qt.QDataStream.Qt_5_10)

        keys = out.readQVariant()
```

I can get all item at keys.

But I can not get it from the C++.

How can I get this QDataStream (QVariantMap)  from c++ ?

```
    QVariantMap *vmat_x;

    QDataStream stream(message);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_10);
    stream >> vmat_x ;
```

vmat_x is always empty

any idea ?

EDIT:

message is QBytearray coming from Python xox

Comment: what is `message`? please provide a [mre]

Comment: How do you pass the QBytearray from python to C++? Do you save it in a file or send it by another means? And if it is by another means, what is that means? That information is needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: sending as Qdatastream through mqt . you save it to file and read same . medum is not changing the behaviour